# Caracal gem on ruby jump to different methods while continue writing on the document

Tags: ruby, docx, caracal

I've been using the Caracal gem for Ruby, and I'm struggling to get it to jump between methods, while still writing to the same document. For example:

```
def main_method
   Caracal::Document.save "test.docx" do |docx|
      docx.p "stuff"
      docx.h1 "more stuff"
      docx.h2 "even more stuff"
            if $var == 1
            method1
            else
            method2
            end
   end
end

def method1
  docx.p "write this"
end

def method2
  docx.p "or write this instead"
end
```

But no, if I jump to another method, it doesn't continue writing in the document, and apparently there is no way with Caracal to open a document, position at the end, and continue writing (like Rubý's File.open('test.txt', 'a')

Anybody knows a way around this? I know I can put the "write this" directly inside the if statements, but this is just a basic example, in reality I need several ramifications as different conditions are met, so I really need to jump to different methods, or it would be a terrible mess.

Thanks community!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `docx` is only in scope within the block attached to the `save` method. In order for the other methods to be able to see and use this variable you will need to pass it as a parameter.

First make the methods accept a parameter, e.g.

```
def method1(docx)
  docx.p "write this"
end
```

then pass the actual variable as an argument when calling the method:

```
#...
if $var == 1
  method1(docx)
else
# etc...
```